# Extend TestController / TestControllerPromise

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am writing my E2E tests with test cafe. The code I am testing is a library that is loaded into other websites and first needs to initialize itself. So every one of my tests starts with the same code:

```
t.switchToIframe(iframeSelector)
 .expect(loginSelectorSpinner).exists).ok({timeout: 3000}) // wait for login start
 .expect(loginSelectorSpinner).exists).notOk({timeout: 5000}) // wait for login finish
```

I would like to move this into helper methods that I can chain like the built-in methods.
So my code would look like this:

```
t.waitForLoginFinish()
 .except(whatever)...
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TestCafe doesn't provide API for that for now. Here is a feature suggestion in the TestCafe Github repository: [Provide an ability to add custom actions to the test controller](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1535). You can vote for it by adding your +1 reaction.